# How to add custom pages in between add to cart and checkout process in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I add some pages in checkout process, like T&C, Coupon code claiming steps, or Participating in a lucky draw to claim coupon code?
I can create those pages, but how do I add those pages after add to cart page, before checkout page?